# Webpack - How to Bundle CommonJS modules (module.export)

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, ecmascript-5

### Is it possible to migrate from grunt to webpack without refactoring to ES6?

Right now I am working on a legacy AngularJS project that uses grunt to build the app.  I want to switch to using webpack so I can also move to Angular in the future.  Now all the files are using the module.exports format instead of the import/export of es6.  All the guides I've found on webpack has examples with es6.  Has anyone moved to webpack without upgrading to es6?

Comment: You can. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, Webpack bundles ES Modules, CommonJS, and AMD modules (even combined). See [Webpack Examples - Mixed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/mixed/README.md).